# Run code when button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and building a game, I use 2 buttons (IncreaseButton, DecreaseButton) the problem I have is that the button callback functions are only called once, when the user clicks on the button but not when the button is held down. How can I make the button to be called repeatedly when held down?

**Code**

```
    public void IncreaseBPM()
{
    if (speed < 12) 
    {
        speed += 0.05f;
        bpmText.GetComponent<BeatTextControl> ().beats += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("savedBPM", speed);
    }
}

public void DecreaseBPM()
{
    if (speed > 1.5)
    {
        speed -= 0.05f;
        bpmText.GetComponent<BeatTextControl> ().beats -= 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("savedBPM", speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a loop that checks to see when a button is being pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so firstly you create 2 booleans:

```
bool increase = false;
bool decrease = false;
```

then you set them inside the functions

```
public void WhenButtonClicked()
    { increase = true; }
public void WhenOtherButtonClicked()
    { decrease = true; }
```

Then in the update function inside the same file you check:

```
Void update(){
   If(increase){ IncreaseBPM(); }
   Else if(decrease){ DecreaseBPM(); } 
}
```

About when the button gets released, i found a simple answer:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/843319/46-gui-button-onrelease.html

> Add an Event Trigger component to your button (In the event menu).
>   From there you can add a listener for OnPointerUp. Treat it just the
>   same as OnClick.

And create 2 other functions that set increase and decrease to false !

Answer (score 1):

Unity's `Button` component does **not** have this functionality built in. You have to roll out your own with the `Image` component as a `Button`. Implement `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` interface then override the `OnPointerDown` and `OnPointerUp` functions.

When `OnPointerDown` is called, use `struct` to store the which object/volume `Image` is clicked and the current click `pointerId` in a `List`.
You can then check which `Image` is clicked in the `Update` function.

If the `OnPointerUp` is called, you have to check which `pointerId` is released then check if that `pointerId` exist in the `List` and remove it if it does.

I have gone ahead to do this. Below is the new script in your question:

```
public class ButtonTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Register to Button events
        ButtonDownRelease.OnButtonActionChanged += ButtonActionChange;
        Debug.Log("Registered!");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    //Un-Register to Button events
    void OnDisable()
    {
        ButtonDownRelease.OnButtonActionChanged -= ButtonActionChange;
    }


    //Will be called when there is a Button action
    void ButtonActionChange(ButtonAction buttonAction)
    {
        //Check for held down
        if (buttonAction == ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonDown)
        {
            Debug.Log("Decrease Button held Down!");
            DecreaseBPM();
        }

        if (buttonAction == ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonDown)
        {
            Debug.Log("Increase Button held Down!");
            IncreaseBPM();
        }

        //Check for release
        if (buttonAction == ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonUp)
        {
            Debug.Log("Decrease Button Released!");
        }

        if (buttonAction == ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonUp)
        {
            Debug.Log("Increase Button Released!");
        }
    }

    private void IncreaseBPM()
    {
        if (TempoController.GetComponent<Pendulum>().speed < 12)
        {
            TempoController.GetComponent<Pendulum>().speed += 0.05f;
        }
    }

    private void DecreaseBPM()
    {
        if (TempoController.GetComponent<Pendulum>().speed > 1.5)
        {
            TempoController.GetComponent<Pendulum>().speed -= 0.05f;
        }
    }
}
```

**Read carefully**.

Create a new script called `ButtonDownRelease` then put the code below into it. Attach the `ButtonDownRelease` script to the `Canvas` The `Canvas` which is the parent of your `Images`/`Buttons` UI GameObjects. Create two `Images` (Increase and Decrease). Create two `tags` called `increase` and `decrease` then put both `Images` in the right `tag`.

**Note**:

You can still use `Button` instead of the `Image` to make this work if you don't want to use the `Image` component. Simply select each `Button` and change the tags to `increase` and `decrease`, then select the `Text` component that is under each `Button` and change their tags `increase` and `decrease` too. *You must change the `Button`'s `Text` tags too if you want to use the `Button` component* with this script. Also, you will have to attach `ButtonDownRelease` to each `Button` not to the `Canvas` like you have to with `Image` component.

Your `ButtonDownRelease` script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ButtonDownRelease : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    List<ButtonInfo> buttonInfo = new List<ButtonInfo>();

    public delegate void ButtonActionChange(ButtonAction buttonAction);
    public static event ButtonActionChange OnButtonActionChanged;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Send Held Button Down events
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonInfo.Count; i++)
        {
            if (buttonInfo[i].buttonPresed == ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonDown)
            {
                dispatchEvent(ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonDown);
            }

            else if (buttonInfo[i].buttonPresed == ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonDown)
            {
                dispatchEvent(ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonDown);
            }
        }
    }

    void dispatchEvent(ButtonAction btAction)
    {
        if (OnButtonActionChanged != null)
        {
            OnButtonActionChanged(btAction);
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Button Down!");
        ButtonInfo bInfo = new ButtonInfo();
        bInfo.uniqueId = eventData.pointerId;
        if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.CompareTag("increase"))
        {
            bInfo.buttonPresed = ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonDown;
            addButton(bInfo);
        }
        else if (eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.CompareTag("decrease"))
        {
            bInfo.buttonPresed = ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonDown;
            addButton(bInfo);
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Button Down!" + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast);
        removeButton(eventData.pointerId);
    }

    void addButton(ButtonInfo bInfo)
    {
        buttonInfo.Add(bInfo);
    }

    void removeButton(int unqID)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonInfo.Count; i++)
        {
            if (unqID == buttonInfo[i].uniqueId)
            {
                //Send Release Button Up events
                if (buttonInfo[i].buttonPresed == ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonDown)
                {
                    dispatchEvent(ButtonAction.DecreaseButtonUp);
                }

                else if (buttonInfo[i].buttonPresed == ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonDown)
                {
                    dispatchEvent(ButtonAction.IncreaseButtonUp);
                }
                buttonInfo.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

    }

    public struct ButtonInfo
    {
        public int uniqueId;
        public ButtonAction buttonPresed;
    }
}

public enum ButtonAction
{
    None,
    IncreaseButtonDown, IncreaseButtonUp,
    DecreaseButtonDown, DecreaseButtonUp
}
```

Finally, you will run into problems if you only use `boolean` variables to do this. This needs to be done with `pointerId` like the script provided in this answer in order to avoid bugs on mobile devices. A good example of this bug is when you click on an `Image` then release the finger on another GameObject, your boolean logic would **break** because `OnPointerUp` won't be called. Also using multi-touch on mobile devices will cause problems too.