# Unity5:how to stop Event trigger Update Selected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created 2 UI buttons and added Event trigger component with event type Update Selected and assigned the down given methods to them , I want the following codes to run until the buttons are pressed and not longer that but when using Update Selected codes keep on running even after the buttons are released.

**CODE**

```
public void IncreaseBPM()
{
    if (speed < 12) 
    {
        speed += 0.05f;
        bpmText.GetComponent<BeatTextControl> ().beats += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("savedBPM", speed);
    }
}

public void DecreaseBPM()
{
    if (speed > 1.5)
    {
        speed -= 0.05f;
        bpmText.GetComponent<BeatTextControl> ().beats -= 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("savedBPM", speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing the-same work with this [person](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39195387/3785314). There are 2 answer there and you should try one of them

Comment: Those solutions are very complex